# Display higher quality images for Facebook posts for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, image

I'm using the Facebook SDK to allow users to share content through my app to their Walls. Its a pretty standard set-up with the Facebook SDK where a typical post will contain some text as well as an image to accompany the post.

This all works fine, but my problem is that since Facebook resizes and converts the images as they see fit, the post images look a bit pixelated when viewed on a Retina display. Does anyone know whether there is a way to ensure that Facebook uses a higher quality image for this?

Again, to clarify, the original images I'm using are high enough quality, but Facebook degrades them a little too much, and they end up not looking too good on a Retina display. Can we avoid this in some way?

Below is an excerpt from the pretty standard Facebook post code I'm using;

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   sharingURL, @"link",
                                   sharingTitle, @"name",
                                   @" ", @"caption",
                                   description, @"description",
                                   actions, @"actions",
                                   picture, @"picture",
                                   nil];

[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Note that the images I'm linking are roughly 250x250px JPGs, if that helps.

**EDIT**: 
Added a sample image to clarify what I mean. I'm trying to see if there's a way to ask Facebook to use a high-res image for retina displays here.

[image: Post image and how it looks on FB]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What code are you using to grab the image and show it later in your app?  Facebook stores several sizes of each picture.  You can usually get the higher quality version with a simple query string parameter, but it depends on how you are getting the image back.

Comment: @Inturbidus, Thanks for the info, but I'm not talking about getting pics from Facebook from my app; rather, uploading / sharing content via my app to FB. I've added a pic to further clarify what I need.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: @Madhu I would suggest you to change the source of the image as per the device rather make it dependent to FB. Check it out in the page I posted how to make it independent. May it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the info Kuldeep, but I'm afraid its not as simple as uploading a higher res image for retina displays. FB will resize this image no matter what, so trying to figure out a way to work around this - if its possible!

Comment: @Madhu Did you find a way to accomplish this since your post in March? It seems crazy that this is still an issue.

Comment: Is anyone at Facebook looking at this post? I think now that practically every iOS device is retina, this is kind of a big deal. Is there a way to flag this to the attention of Facebook personnel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update your Photo in the user's photo albums. This will also result in a wall post. (If that also fits in your case.) That would be the code:

```
// save image as data
UIImage* image = [...];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8);
[params setValue: imageData forKey: @"source"];

// send post request
Facebook* facebook = [...];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath: @"me/photos" andParams: params andHttpMethod: @"POST" andDelegate: delegate];
```

(Note: Uploaded images for the albums must be smaller than 960px on each side. see: [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/))

Comment: Thanks very much for your time jaydee. Are you referring to actually posting a photo on someone's wall? I added a sample pic in my question for clarity, just in case the Q wasn't too clear.

Comment: well this was just another idea, how to bring higher quality images to facebook. im not referring an actual wallpost, but an automatic wallpost will be created, when a user uploads photos. I guess you *cannot* change the default facebook image size for wallposts.

Comment: I agree. Still haven't got an answer to this I'm afraid, but it does look like there is no way to work this out. I'll be leaving the question itself unanswered, but seeing that the bounty will expire in an hour, I'll just put in on ya. No reason letting it go to waste :)

Answer (score 2):

may be these link useful to you :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1578/how-to-get-a-user-profile-with-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2)    
{       
    //iPhone 4
   //Use @2x images here
    NSLog(@"iPhone 4");
}
else 
{
    //iPhone 3 or earlier
   //Use original images here
   NSLog(@"iPhone 3 or earlier");
}


//May this will help you.
```

I would suggest you to change the source of the image as per the device rather make it dependent to FB.